# Is it possible to separate a bi-directional edge in gephi?

Tags: r, graph, visualization, social-networking, gephi

I have imported a GraphML file I built in R into Gephi. The file contains a list of edges from 1 node to another. Nodes that point to each other are combined into 1 bi-directional edge. Is it possible to separate the edges? (Gephi forum seems to be 404)

Example:

- Node A -> Node B
- Node A -> Node B
- Node B -> Node A

Gephi is turning this into 1 edge of weight 3.

I would like to show 2 edges:

- 1 from A -> B with weight of 2
- 1 from B -> A with weight of 1.

If Gephi can't do this, do you know of another program (Or R package?) that can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `igraph` for example:

```
library(igraph)
graph_from_literal(A-+B, A-+B, B-+A, simplify=F) %>%
  set_edge_attr("width", value = 1) %>%
  simplify(edge.attr.comb = list(width="sum", "ignore")) %>%
  plot(edge.curved = .5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but that can be handled within gephi at the preview workspace:

1. Go to the **Preview Settings** side panel
2. Look for the **Edges** section
3. Check the **Curved** attribute option

**[see example screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTrP.png)**